# probable cause of excel files getting corrupted

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

how to find out the probable cause of corruption of excel files...here i m not saying of a single file...files are getting corrupted one after the other...can

1)using windows 8 with excel 2007 and storing the files in .xls be a cause?

2)this files are shared files and are opened in both xp and windows 8 can this be a cause

3)how can i check if my excel source files have got corrupted?

or any other probalbe cause for the file to get corrupted.
thanks in advance

Comment: If its a recent thing then it could also be a sign of an upcoming hard disk or memory failure.  I would run checks on both.

Answer (score 1):

You say the files are "shared files". Does that mean that you have the "Share Workbook" feature enabled? If so, don't worry any more. Sharing workbooks so that multiple users can edit a file is a recipe for disaster. Shared files will eventually become corrupt, impossible to troubleshoot or repair. It's not a question of **if** it will happen, but rather **when** it will happen.

There is nothing you can do to repair corrupt shared files.

If you need simultaneous multi-user read/write access to your data, then Excel shared files is **NOT** the way to go. This Excel feature is riddled with bugs and results in unexpected behaviour.

If you use shared files, be certain to have a strict backup regime, because the files can become corrupt at any time.

For safe multi-user edit access to your data, you may want to explore a database solution like Access or SQL instead. Excel can still be the front end for data entry and reporting, but it was never designed to be a multi-user interface for Excel data.

Comment: yes this are shaed workbook..but my question is that why at this point of time most of my files are getting...this are not created recenty(for some it has been years and for some months) i never faced this problem before.what could be the reasons that most of the files getting corrupted recenty(because i musing shared workbook for a long time and that all workbook are getting corrupted now either they are old or new)

Comment: Well, Excel specialists all over the world warn about shared workbooks. The thing is, you never know when or why they can become corrupt, behave strangely, don't save, don't calculate correctly, etc. Once a shared workbook goes bad, it's impossible to troubleshoot. There is no specific **why** or **why now**. That's the risk. It can happen any time. If you've been using them for years, well, you are lucky that you have not run into trouble before. Now go find an alternative before it's too late.

Comment: seems like a bad excuse for not using the feature. If so, why is that feature there in the first place if its not to be used?

Comment: Seems like a good excuse for not using the feature. Microsoft has several dodgy things out there like `Offline Files` that eventually punish those who hardheadedly ignore empirically derived warnings from the software userbase. If you use `Offline Files` long enough, you will find one day, they only exist in the cache, not on the server and if something blows the cache, oops! Same goes for Shared Workbooks on Excel... Poof into the bit bucket.